# outlook 2007 - auto suggest email recipients names sent to or read from in the past

Tags: outlook-2007

can anyone tell me the setting in outlook 2007 that would enable the hints of email addresses and contact names when generating an email to someone who you received or wrote to in the past.

i am tired of typing things out all the time and know it auto populates names for me on my other machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

- On the Tools menu, click Options.
- On the Preferences tab, click E-mail Options, and then click Advanced E-mail Options.
- Select the "**Suggest names while completing To, Cc, and Bcc fields**" check box.